# Getting wrong address from ECDSA.recover()

Tags: solidity, signature, ethers.js, ecdsa

I'm signing typed data using `_signTypedData()` method of ethers. But when I retrieve the signer's address in Solidity Smart Contract using `ECDSA.recover()`, it returns the wrong address.
Let me know if I'm missing anything or taking the wrong approach. I'd really appreciate any help!

Front-End Code

```
let token = {
    tokenId: 1,
    account: "<< my_wallet_address >>"
};
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
let signature;
let oContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, provider);
$("#btnSignTransaction").on("click", async function () {
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const {
        chainId
    } = await provider.getNetwork();
    signature = await signer._signTypedData({
            name: 'Name',
            version: '1.0.0',
            chainId: chainId,
            verifyingContract: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
        }, {
            NFT: [{
                    name: 'tokenId',
                    type: 'uint256'
                },
                {
                    name: 'account',
                    type: 'address'
                },
            ],
        },
        token
    );
    token.signature = signature;
});

$("#btnCall").on("click", async function () {
    const addressFromContract = await oContract.getAccountAddress(token.account, token.tokenId, token.signature);
    console.log(addressFromContract);
});
```

Solidity Code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol"; 

contract ERC721LazyMintWith712 is ERC721, EIP712, AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol)
        ERC721(name, symbol)
        EIP712(name, "1.0.0")
    {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
    }

    function _hash(address account, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        view
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        return
            _hashTypedDataV4(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encode(
                        keccak256("NFT(uint256 tokenId,address account)"),
                        tokenId,
                        account
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    function _verify(bytes32 digest, bytes memory signature)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        return hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, ECDSA.recover(digest, signature));
    }

    function getAccountAddress(address account, uint256 tokenId, bytes calldata signature) external view returns(address) {
        return ECDSA.recover(_hash(account, tokenId), signature);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement ERC721LazyMintWith712.sol Smart Contract from [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/workshops/tree/master/06-nft-merkle-drop) repo.
However, When I test the contract by creating Test Cases, it works perfectly but, With Front-End integration, it doesn't!

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question and went through the Ethers.js code as well as the draft-EIP712.sol code, but kept having the same result as you.

The codes are entirely correct and adhere to [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712). My best guess is that you were probably using a test blockchain environment such as ganache / ganache-cli which has a very specific behavior:

- networkId returned by RPC is 1337 by default
- chainId returned by [CHAINID Opcode](https://www.ethervm.io/#46) is 1 by default.

With this line:

```
const { chainId } = await provider.getNetwork();
```

You are actually getting the networkId, not the chainId that draft-EIP712.sol gets with `block.chainid`. So the different Ids lead to different data, different hashes, and therefore different signatures.

While you can hardcode a chainId of 1 in your JavaScript code, the cleanest solution is to use the `--chainId X` flag on ganache where `X` can be replaced by the chainId of your choice (*i.e.,* 1337) and it will ensure that both RPC chainId and Opcode chainID are the same value.

With `ganache-cli --chainId 1337`, your code works fine with Remix or MetaMask, with Hardhat chainId and networkId being coherent between RPC and Opcode by default.

A second ongoing [issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/10290) with MetaMask (I assume that you were using it) is that the default `http://localhost:8545` endpoint is assumed to have a chainId of 1337, which might not be the case with Hardhat or a specific configuration of ganache that can also lead to a wrong signature on the client side but should forbid sending any tx too. Either set your node to a chainId of 1337 or create your own MetaMask endpoint.

So your code is fine. It's definitely a configuration issue either with MetaMask / Ganache or Hardhat as described above.

Comment: I did deploy to rinkeby and still have same issue, i will try to use eth-sig-util now to confirm which one wrong, encoding with ethers or decoding with ecdsa

Comment: @DellWatson Did you try to use `eth-sig-util`? If so, did it solve the problem?

Comment: @Dell Watson, Yash Gajjar Is this issue resolved? I am also facing same issue on Mumbai polygon